# Vertical scroll bar is not visible when i moved horizant scroll bar extreme left

Tags: java, javascript, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF with richfaces 3.2 but i am facing problem with scrollbar in extended table 
when i moved horizontal scroll bar extreme left  then Vertical scroll bar is not visible .

When i move horizontal scroll bar towards middle/extreme right then only Vertical scroll bar is  visible .

Is it possible to make vertical scroll bar always visible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware about any such issues, as at chrome the scrollbar [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable&sample=edt-builtin-sorting-and-filtering&skin=blueSky) working fine...

if it's related to IE then workaround: `set for rich:panel position: relative`

Comment: The showcase you're linking is for RF 4, the RF 3 showcase can be found here [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?c=extendedDataTable&tab=usage)

Comment: So, if the issue is with original controller, than you may report bug .. ANd you can use latest version if possible..

Comment: This issue i am getting with extendedtable component.u mean to add rich:panel on top of extendedtable and set position: relative?